# Host as Router and connect KVM VMs

Tags: linux, networking, kvm

I would like to configure my host as router and configure each of the VM to connect to the host router in different network. I'm using KVM to run VMs on my debian host. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a single host-only network and configure VLANs for the attached guests so that they do not see each other (but I am not familiar with that) or you create a separate host-only network for each guest (with `virsh net-define ...` or `virsh net-edit ...`) like this:

```
<network>
  <name>private0</name>
  <uuid>a2422899-d29b-9055-4bf7-1995fd6af4b8</uuid>
  <bridge name='private0' stp='off' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:29:c3:aa'/>
</network>
```

(Leave out uuid and mac when defining.)

Comment: If you are using `virtmanager` you can define routed networks from there, so no additional routing configuration on the host is necessary.